# VectorDrawable bug after updating Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, icons, android-drawable

I updated Android Studio to Giraffe and updated my dependencies to the newest version, also migrating from kapt to ksp. Since then my Icons behave weird. The appearances changes when recomposing (The lower Icon in the second screenshot is how the icons should look like. In both screenshot there are the same two icons with different colors above each other):

[image: Icons are weirdly displayed] [image: Lower Icon is how it should be displayed]

I am using the Material Icons from google, without modification, just downloaded and imported them as VectorDrawables to the res/drawable folder.

My Icon script (Default material3 Icon):

```
Icon(painter = painterResource(id = icon),
        contentDescription = null,
        tint = iconColor
    )
```

My relevant Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.6.0-alpha03'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.5.0'
debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.5.0'
debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.0'
ksp 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
compose_version = '1.5.1'
id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.9.0-1.0.13' apply false
```

I tried using Image instead of Icon and tested on different devices with different android versions. I also re-downloaded the Material Icons and tried custom ones but all with the same result. Before updating, all Icons where displayed correctly and I didn't change anything else.

My target and compile sdk is 34, but I tested with Android Studio Hedgehog using Gradle 8.2 (which is recommended for sdk 34), also with the same result

Answer (score 0):

I found the responsible Gradle implementation but not the actual cause.

```
androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2
```

AnimatedContent, Icons and Images behave weird in this version. After downgrading to 1.7.1 everything works fine again